# Saving regular expression matches into an array in Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, pattern-matching

I hope you can guide me in that I'm doing wrong.

I have for example:

```
my $text = "<some tag>  stuff here> </some tag> mer mer <some tag> 'more stuff' </some tag>";

 @b =($text =~ m/s(.)uff/gsi);
 print "array B, size: ",  @b+0,  ", elements: ";
 print join (" ,", @b);
 print "\n";


 @c =($text =~ m/<some tag>(.+)<\/some tag>/g);
 print "array C, size: ",  @c+0,  ", elements: ";
 print join (", ", @c);
 print "\n";
```

The output is as follows:

```
array B, size: 2, elements: t ,t
array C, size: 1, elements:   stuff here> </some tag> mer mer <some tag> 'more stuff'
```

I am interested in the output of array C being

```
size 2: , elements stuff here , 'more stuff'
```

why does it skip it?

Comment: It's 2013. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

```
/<some tag>(.+?)<\/some tag>/
```

will do the trick if they can't be nested.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the shortest match in the string, use *non-greedy* search `(.+?)`.

Else for the longest matching string you can make the search *greedy* `(.+)`.

For better understanding please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106250/how-does-pattern-matching-works-in-perl/15106472#15106472) link.

Hence, right answer would be the answer given by ikegami.